# Working with Searchable Spinner in Android.....?

Tags: android, android-spinner

When I am using simple spinner then output will show correctly. In details with text and checkbox when using this lines:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)find View By Id(R.id.spinner);

// create an Array Adapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
Array Adapter<Char Sequence> adapter = Array Adapter . create From Resource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But, when I am using searchable spinner with external library for implementing search functionality in spinner  then checkbox will not show. How to solve this problem ? Or `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` is not supporting searchable spinner.

Comment: you need to make custom adapter for spinner..

Comment: is there any reference then please provide.

Comment: @PravinKumbhar did you solved the problem?